Where a father, who is being brainwashed by terrorists, is searching for his missing daughter who is working at growing replacement body parts
Looking for the title of a sci-fi novel I read, where a father is looking for his presumed missing daughter, he later has a realisation about the real circumstances in her leaving. In the plot a terrorist organisation gets him involved in a scheme for an attack with ever increasing brain washing. The daughter in the mean time is living in a commune type environment where scientists are growing replacement parts for wealthy people, I remember her tending the "pumps" to the arm growing machines. I recall a scene where the father has a bike accident blamed on a malfunctioning digital assistant and another scene where he must act as courier using his bike.
It was a dystopian setting and the tech was typical near future It's a relatively recent read, written in recent time. I do not remember the cover art, but an ending where the girl has survived and has discovered advanced bioengineering. Has echoes of 84K.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?  Other than growing replacement parts, how advanced was the technology?  Do you recall the cover art?

It was a dystopian setting, the tech was typical near future, it's a relatively recent read, written in recent time. I do not remember the cover art, but an ending where the girl has survived and has discovered advanced bioengineering. Has echoes of 84K

I eventually remembered I had borrowed it from the library, and luckily they had a log of my borrowing history, the name of the book was Zero Bomb by Matt Hill.

The near future. Following the death of his daughter Martha, Remi flees the north of England for London. Here he tries to rebuild his life as a cycle courier, delivering subversive documents under the nose of an all-seeing state.
But when a driverless car attempts to run him over, Remi soon discovers that his old life will not let him move on so easily. Someone is leaving coded messages for Remi across the city, and they seem to suggest that Martha is not dead at all.
Unsure what to believe, and increasingly unable to trust his memory, Remi is slowly drawn into the web of a dangerous radical whose '70s sci-fi novel is now a manifesto for direct action against automation, technology, and England itself.
The deal? Remi can see Martha again - if he joins the cause.

